# iOS7 - Search results tableview pushed 20px down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

All my search results tableviews are offset by about 20-30px. All my view controllers are coded by hand, so there's no storyboards or xibs. I have tried:

- Setting `Status bar is initially hidden` in info.plist
- Setting `self.wantsFullScreenLayout = true`
- Setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
- Setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;`
- Setting the search results tableview's frame to a Y origin of -20

None of these are working. Instead each search results tableview appears as such:[image]
[image]

Are there any workarounds? Is there anything I can set? I have tried I have inspected the search results tableview frame and it is at a Y origin of 0.

Comment: I had the same problem and found a so-called solution yet it leaves a space between your tableView and spotlight. The solution is decreasing the tableView's height by 20 and increasing y value by 20.

Comment: i solved my problem. did you used uicontrol

Answer (score 3):

add this line:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

check [developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/190474?tstart=250) may be it help you

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I tried that too and no luck. same result

Answer (score 0):

Test if the device is running iOS 7 and adjust the frame of your view 20px up in `viewDidload`. I had this problem with my table view and fixed it as follows:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    CGRect frame = self.myTable.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= 20;
    self.myTable.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    CGRect frame = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -20;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame = frame;
}
```

put it in this method

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```